How to resolve AttributeError and BadRequestError in Python using LangChain and AzureOpenAI?
I'm working on integrating LangChain with AzureOpenAI in Python and encountering a couple of issues. I've recently updated from a deprecated method to a new class implementation, but now I'm stuck with some errors I don't fully understand. Here's the relevant part of my code:
from langchain_openai import AzureOpenAI as LCAzureOpenAI
# from langchain.llms import AzureOpenAI <-- Deprecated

# Create client accessing LangChain's class
client = LCAzureOpenAI(
    openai_api_version=api_version,
    azure_deployment=deployment_name,
    azure_endpoint=azure_endpoint,
    temperature=TEMPERATURE,
    max_tokens=MAX_TOKENS,
    model=model
    #,model_kwargs={'azure_openai_api_key': api_key}
)

# Attempt to send a chat message
client.chat("Hi")

This results in the following error:
AttributeError: 'AzureOpenAI' object has no attribute 'chat'

When I replace client.chat("Hi") with client.invoke("Hi"), I get a different error:
BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'error': {'code': 'OperationNotSupported', 'message': 'The completion operation does not work with the specified model, gpt-4. Please choose different model and try again. You can learn more about which models can be used with each operation here: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2197993.'}}

How can I resolve these errors?
Any guidance or insights into these errors and how to resolve them would be greatly appreciated!
